# How could i loop this query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following sql query in Oracle.

```
SELECT pr.uuid AS masterproductid, 
            (case 
                when xmltype(pr.attributes_de_de).extract('//attr[@name = "SellingPoint1"]/string/text()') IS NOt NULL THEN 'sellingpoint1'
                when xmltype(pr.attributes_de_de).extract('//attr[@name = "SellingPoint2"]/string/text()') IS NOt NULL THEN 'sellingpoint2'
            END
            ) as testt
  FROM product pr WHERE pr.defaultproductvariationid =(SELECT prv.uuid FROM  productvariation prv WHERE  prv.uuid = '3rep_vEBP6IAAAE83REjnPbb' AND pr.typecode='16')
```

In the case-when both 'sellingpoint1' and 'sellingpoint2' is not null but this query returns only sellingpoint1, i want 'sellingpoint2' also how can i get that?

Thanks for help

Comment: You want both values in one column?

Comment: no, i want  values in two columns

Comment: But then your query should always return 3 total columns. Just use 2 different `CASE` statements instead of 2 conditions in the same `CASE`.

Comment: @user964147 - and add sample data or use select... from dual in your code examples.

Answer (score 0):

This puts it into two columns:

```
SELECT pr.uuid AS masterproductid, 
            (case when xmltype(pr.attributes_de_de).extract('//attr[@name = "SellingPoint1"]/string/text()') IS NOt NULL
                 THEN 'sellingpoint1'
             end) as testsellingpoint1,
            (case when xmltype(pr.attributes_de_de).extract('//attr[@name = "SellingPoint2"]/string/text()') IS NOt NULL
                  THEN 'sellingpoint2'
             END
            ) as testsellingpoint2
  FROM product pr WHERE pr.defaultproductvariationid =(SELECT prv.uuid FROM  productvariation prv WHERE  prv.uuid = '3rep_vEBP6IAAAE83REjnPbb' AND pr.typecode='16')
```